# Different screen orientations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

i need some help in addition to android-layouts.
For eyample:

Actually I use a view called daily.xml.These view contains a flipper, which is filled programmatically with 5 ListViews to flip around if the user want to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background">

    <de.oszimtcc.timetableview.TimetableFlipperView
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
    </de.oszimtcc.timetableview.TimetableFlipperView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Flipper in TimetableScreen.java

```
    activity.setContentView(R.layout.daily);
    Log.i(TimetableApplication.LOG_TAG,"Start create Timetable-Aplication");
    activity.setContentView(R.layout.daily);   

    activity.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);     
    flipper = (TimetableFlipperView) activity.findViewById(R.id.flipper); 
    dayListView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.dayListView);
    flipper.AddContent(**Content to show **);
```

Now, I want to add a landscapemode.In these mode i won't hava such flipper, cause there is enough space to show all ListViews on a horizontal linear layout.So i created a layout-land Resource-Folder an add another daily.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<de.oszimtcc.timetableview.BlockListView
    android:id="@+id/dayListViewMonday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/day_selector"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent">
</de.oszimtcc.timetableview.BlockListView>

...the same ListView again for 4 times, with different android:id...

</LinearLayout>
```

But how can i handle this into my TimetableScreen.java Class?Because there is no flipper i can't use my default-constructor to init the class.Should I call different methods every time the onCreate is called or is there any nicer possibility to handle it?

Thanks a lot Kooki!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`, in order to find out the screen orientation. If its a landscape mode, dont initialize the flipper variable.
I just added one line in your code, ***check the if control statement***.

```
 activity.setContentView(R.layout.daily);
Log.i(TimetableApplication.LOG_TAG,"Start create Timetable-Aplication");
activity.setContentView(R.layout.daily);   

if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_POTRAIT) {   //Check this statement
activity.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);     
flipper = (TimetableFlipperView) activity.findViewById(R.id.flipper); 
dayListView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.dayListView);
flipper.AddContent(**Content to show **);
} else {
//Code for Landscape mode
}
```